Issue with Data Sync for Power BI Reports in large data set of SharePoint list
This is regarding a critical issue we are encountering with our Power BI reports in the production environment. We need to load data from a SharePoint list that contains approximately 150,000 items. We are  facing challenges with data synchronization.
Here are the details of the issue:
•   SharePoint List Items: Approximately 150,000
•   Power BI License: Pro
•   Issue: Data synchronization failure during sync
Given the substantial increase in data volume, it appears that our current configuration is not able to handle the load efficiently. This is impacting the performance and reliability of our Power BI reports.
Could you please advise on the following:

Are there any best practices or optimization techniques we can apply to improve data sync performance with such a large dataset?
Would upgrading to a different Power BI licensing plan, such as Premium, provide better performance for handling large datasets?
Are there any specific configurations or settings in Power BI or SharePoint that we need to adjust to facilitate smoother data synchronization?

We tried below options
Option 1: Using Data flow
Result: Tried using data flow, data refresh was taking more then 2 hours and it was breaking the refresh as the limitation of data refresh in Data flow is 2 hours.
Option 2: Using SharePoint List Views
Result: Tried this method. there is a limitation of single default view. Custom views created for different scenario is not supported. We can select only one view (default) while loading the SharePoint list through SharePoint Online connector.

Experiment with using OData to see if it is more performant...
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Getting-data-from-SharePoint-Online-List-vs-OData-Feed/td-p/356552
and https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/get-sharepoint-list-items-in-power-bi/
